# exception in thread main java.lang.arrayindexoutofboundsexception 1

Tags: arrays

well i have to make a java program which determinate if a given number is capicua(131,12121,13431) the same number from last to initial digit. but it gives me the error, in the line 23 (while(i>=0).....) the question is how can i call the array into thath while. pls help me im really sad :c. Here is the code:

```
public class Capi {
    /**
     *
     **/
    public static int num(int a) { // counting digits from the number
    int n = 0;
    while(a>=10) {    a = a/10;
            n = n+1;
           }
    return n;
    }
    public static boolean det(int a, int n) {
    int z = a;
    double y =0;
    n = n-1;
    int i = 0;
    int x[] = new int[n];
    for(i=0; i<x.length; i++) { // saving the digits into x[i]
        x[i] = a%10;
        a = a/10;
        }
    while(i>=0) { y = x[i]*Math.pow(10,n-1); // calling the digits x[i],x[i-1]   untill it gets 0
        i = i - 1;
        n = n -1;
            }
    double num1= y + a*Math.pow(10,n);
    if(num1 == z) { return true; }
    else { return false; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please dont dump the code. Format it and post your question.

Comment: Hey Mike. What line is throwing the exception? What are you trying to accomplish with this code? Your goal is unclear, and knowing what the code is supposed to do will help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Please use {code} snippet to add code. Its easier for others to help quickly.

Comment: Can you share you main function?, It will allow us run and see what your trying to accomplish. Its still not very clear what arguments are passed and whats the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel the issue is that the value of i is set to x.length, before you attempt `while(i>=0)`. I have hence added `i--` before you run the loop.

See if the following does the trick.

```
public class Capi {

public static int num(int a) { // counting digits from the number
    int n = 0;
    while(a>=10) {
        a = a/10;
        n = n+1;
    }
    return n;
}

public static boolean det(int a, int n) {
    int z = a;
    double y = 0;
    n = n-1;
    int i = 0;
    int x[] = new int[n];

    for(i=0; i<x.length; i++) { // saving the digits into x[i]
        x[i] = a%10;
        a = a/10;
    }

    //i is now set to x.length, thus decrement it as index runs from 0 to x.length-1
    i=i-1;

    while(i>=0) {
        y = x[i]*Math.pow(10,n-1); // calling the digits x[i],x[i-1]   untill it gets 0
        i = i - 1;
        n = n -1;
    }

    double num1= y + a*Math.pow(10,n);
    if(num1 == z) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi, i don't think it wuold be the thing, because its from 0 to <x.length, so variable "i" being an integer will have the correct size, thanks anyway im happy for any help

Comment: @Mike, The value of i when for loop terminates is `x.length or n`. Arrays in java are indexed from 0 to array.length -1. Hence, you can only do `x[0] through x[x.length-1]`, but in your case `i=x.length`, so it will throw index of out bound exception. Check this out http://ideone.com/qWmPMW . Hope this helps, enjoy!

Comment: What the.... OMG! you're right, man if you were here i'd give you a kiss, thank you, thank you thank you thank you Math.pow(thank you,n)

srry im rlly noob at programming. you're right.!

Comment: @Mike, Glad it worked. If it solved your issue, you can accept my answer & that will mark issue closed. Enjoy!

Comment: yes, i hadn't noticed that for the condition i<x.length works, first i have to get a i>x.length value. ty soo much, i don't know how to accept the answer, im new :$, this page is in english and that's not my native language

Comment: Looks like you figured it out. Good luck learning java, its a fun language.